# GridLayout doesn't apper

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I am using this `GridLayout` which works find on api 26, but when I try on an 22 api phone it shows only a navigation drawer and a blank screen.
I am using this dependency for cardview

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/ortho_docs"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout style="@style/grid_cards">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_orthopedics" />
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/dept_headers"
                        android:text="@string/ortho" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`

You may need to add this to your gradle `implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0-rc01'`

Comment: androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0 is released as of this date, so you can also use that instead of this release candidate